# Friend function of a private inner class

Tags: c++, private, friend

I have the following problem. I have a class with a private inner class. I now would like to implement a friend swap function for the inner class. However I do not know how to make a non inline swap function. If I define it in the inner class it all works fine. If someone can show me how to make it non inline I would greatly appreciate it :)

Some code do illustrate the problem:

```
class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
        int data;

        friend swap(Inner& lhs, Inner& rhs)  // what is the syntax to 
        {                                    // make this function non inline?
            using std::swap;
            swap(lhs.data, rhs.data);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could re-word your question a little bit?

Comment: @GIJoe If there is something that could be written more clearly I would be happy to do it. You will have to be more specific though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Seemed a bit strange to me at first, but it makes sense. When I tried to write the definition of the swap function in the .cpp file the compiler told me that swap does not have access to Inner since it is private. The solution was to make it this swap function a friend of Outer as well!

In code:

.h:

```
class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
        int data;

        friend swap(Inner& lhs, Inner& rhs);     
    }
    friend swap(Inner& lhs, Inner& rhs);
}
```

.cpp:

```
void swap(Outer::Inner& lhs, Outer::Inner& rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.data, rhs.data);
}
```

Comment: Because it not only accesses Outer's private nested class Inner (for that it must be Outer's friend), but also Inner's private member data (for that it must be Inner's friend). Yes, a function can be friend of more than one class, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yes exactly. It seemed strange to me at first because I imagined a deep nesting and how it would look to write so many friend declarations :) However, if you have a deep nesting of private classes you probably have a design problem anyway, so that is not a real problem often :)

Answer (score 1):

To do it you need to define it in a .cpp file just like any other function:

```
Outer::Inner::swap(Outer::Inner& lhs, Outer::Inner& rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.data, rhs.data);
}
```

Comment: I suppose that would work if swap was a member function (static in this case). But it is not meant to be. Perhaps it must be though?

Comment: Sorry, it was my misunderstanding. I think you need to add your solution as an answer.